# MEF - Two way import and export

Tags: events, import, export, mef, aggregation

I'm using MEF in order to execute plugins code in my project.
1. I'm loading my dll sources :

```
   public void AssembleComponents()
    {
        try
        {
            //Creating an instance of aggregate catalog. It aggregates other catalogs
            var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();

            //Build the directory path where the parts will be available
            var directoryPath =
                string.Concat(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
                            .Split('\\').Reverse().Skip(4).Reverse().Aggregate((a, b) => a + "\\" + b)
                            , "\\", "ExportComponents\\Components");


            string localPath = new Uri(directoryPath).LocalPath;
            //Load parts from the available dlls in the specified path using the directory catalog
            var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(localPath, "*.dll");

            //Load parts from the current assembly if available
            var asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            //Add to the aggregate catalog
            aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);
            aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(asmCatalog);

            //Crete the composition container
            var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

            // Composable parts are created here i.e. the Import and Export components assembles here
            container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

2. I'm going through my plugins and executing a "Validate" method :

   ```
   public List<string> Validate(string operationType)
   {
       List<string> res = null;
       foreach (System.Lazy<IValidationRules, IPluginMetadata> plugin in ChekcsPlugins)
       {
           if (plugin.Metadata.DisplayName == operationType)
           {
               res = plugin.Value.Validate();
               break;
           }
       }
       return res;
   }
   ```

I'm know how to export back a returned value once the "Validate" is done but what i need is to return values at run time back during the method execution.
Is it possible?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by 'return values at run time back during the method execution'? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The validate method is implemented on separate dlls. as you can see it returns a value back to "res" variable. I want to stream back values (strings for instance) during the validate execution and not 1 returned value in the end.